# Combine change, blur, and ready callback methods

Tags: jquery

Is there any way I can combine the following 3 jQuery statements?

```
$("#search_building").change(function () {
    var building = $("#search_building").val();
    var room = $("#search_room").val();
    var dept = $("#dept").val();
    var dataString = 'room=' + room + '&' + 'building=' + building + '&' + 'dept=' + dept;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "process_building.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function (html) {
            $('#search_room').html(html);
        }
    });
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "process_timetableMon.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function (html) {
            $('#grid2_mon').html(html);
        }
    });
});

$("#search_building").blur(function () {
    var building = $("#search_building").val();
    var room = $("#search_room").val();
    var dept = $("#dept").val();
    var dataString = 'room=' + room + '&' + 'building=' + building + '&' + 'dept=' + dept;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "process_building.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function (html) {
            $('#search_room').html(html);
        }
    });
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "process_timetableMon.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function (html) {
            $('#grid2_mon').html(html);
        }
    });
});

$("#search_building").ready(function () {
    var building = $("#search_building").val();
    var room = $("#search_room").val();
    var dept = $("#dept").val();
    var dataString = 'room=' + room + '&' + 'building=' + building + '&' + 'dept=' + dept;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "process_timetableMon.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function (html) {
            $('#grid2_mon').html(html);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on) supports binding the same handler to multiple events, and is the appropriate method to use to do so in jQuery 1.7+.

```
$("#search_building").on("change blur", function () {
    // your code here
});
```

As for your ready handler, there is no real `ready` event, and jQuery generally ignores the selector in that case and executes on DOM ready in any case. You can simply trigger `blur` on DOM ready:

```
$(function() {
    $('#search_building').blur();
});
```